# Grouping by two values in same table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table on the format

```
Ship_type | userid | Message
```

Neither of these columns are unique.
I want to count how many (unique) user id's that belong to each ship type, and thus find out which ship type is the most popular.

Example:

```
Ship_type     | userid| Message
-------------- ------- ----------
Sailboat      | 34241 | hello
Sailboat      | 34241 | hi
Sailboat      | 34241 | I'm on a boat!
Fishingvessel | 31245 | yo
Fishingvessel | 98435 | hi there
```

Here we see that there are two different fishingvessels and one sailboat.

If I do the following query:

```
 select ship_type, count(ship_type) FROM db1.MessageType5 GROUP BY ship_type ORDER BY count(ship_type) ASC;
```

I get

```
Sailboat      | 3
Fishingvessel | 2
```

which is wrong - as it counts the number of messages belonging to each ship_type.

**Desired result:**

```
Fishingvessel | 2
Sailboat      | 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `COUNT` `DISTINCT` user ids (and `ORDER BY` ... `DESC` if you want the provided result):

```
SELECT ship_type, COUNT(DISTINCT userid) as cnt
FROM db1.MessageType5 
GROUP BY ship_type 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

- See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8b04/4).